# Deploy 2 SmartContracts at the same address

Tags: contract-deployment, balances

There are 2 SmartContract A, B. First, deploy A, then deploy B at the same address of A.
When I call address(this).balance on A and B, it returns the same result. Would you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy contracts will have the same address with storage values shared among them. Only the implementation of contracts B & A differs. So the state variable remains the same.

Refer https://blog.openzeppelin.com/proxy-patterns/ for more info